# libpango 64-bit on 32-bit Debian Wheezy

Tags: linux, 64-bit, debian, libraries

I have a 32-bit Debian Wheezy install with a 64-bit kernel also installed.  (64-bit kernel, 32-bit userland.)  I need to run a 64-bit binary that depends on libpango, so I need to install 64-bit libpango.  (If I compile this app as 32-bit it works, but I need 64 support.) I tried doing this using multiarch, but I get the following.  How do I install 64-bit libpango on 32-bit Debian so that I can run this code?

```
$ sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-0:amd64Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpango1.0-0:amd64 : Depends: libcairo2:amd64 (>= 1.8.10-3) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfontconfig1:amd64 (>= 2.8.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libfreetype6:amd64 (>= 2.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (>= 2.27.0) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libxft2:amd64 (> 2.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: x-ttcidfont-conf:amd64 but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Answer (score 0):

Install all the packages it depends on first.

`apt` should do this automatically if it knows where to fid those packages.

For more information, type `man apt` or `man apt-get`.

Comment: 1.  Shouldn't apt do this automatically?  2.  When I do I get similar error messages about broken packages.

Comment: It should do it automatically if it knows where to find those packages.